# Backbone History back button issue of browser

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I Have following routes in Backbone:

```
routes: {
   // Default
   's*query':'search',
   '*actions': 'defaultAction'
},
```

with `PushState = true`
Router is working **fine** but when i am using browser back and forward button, query is coming as **undefined**:

```
app_router.on('route:search', function (query) {
   this.passInData = query.split("?",2)[1];
   LazyLoader.loadController([this.controllerMap.sc], this);
});
```

Any Help !!

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery-BBQ Plugin will be perfect solution.
Plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Here the Article about it.
http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/05/managing-history-in-backbone-widgets.html